# AOS service is depending on unused local instance of SQL

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012

Our production AOS server is configured to point to a remote SQL Server instance (per Server Configuration). there is also a local instance of SQL installed that may have been used at one point many moons ago, but definitely not anymore.

Every time we stop the local SQL instance, it also stops the AOS service, which affects production.  If I go to services, and look at the properties of the AOS service, the Dependencies tab clearly shows that the service depends on the SQL instance.

We are trying to clean up unused instances of SQL, but I cannot find out where this dependency has been defined, thus can't stop it because it stops the AOS service too.  Any idea?

[image: AOS service showing dependency]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`sc.exe`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc990290.aspx) to configure service.

Example:

```
sc.exe config "AOS$01" depend= ""
```

PS: in PowerShell use `/` (forward slash) instead of empty string.

Comment: Would that remove all dependencies?  I only want to remove sql server. Do I have to add back the rpc dependency afterwards?

Comment: Ok figured it out, set depends= and add the list of dependencies, it will overwrite current list of dependencies.